the value of cpufreq-info -w and cpufreq-info -f are very different
Environment:
# uname -r
5.15.0-91-generic
# lscpu
Architecture:            x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Address sizes:         52 bits physical, 57 bits virtual
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  384
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-383
Vendor ID:               AuthenticAMD
Model name:            AMD EPYC 9654 96-Core Processor
# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

Problem description:
When i want to get the current cpu clock, i got below result, why they are very different and which value the right value of the logic cpu.
# cpufreq-info -c 1 -w -m
2.40 GHz

# cpufreq-info -c 1 -f -m
3.70 GHz

More info
# cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor
performance
# cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
3699847



Each core's clock frequency may change constantly, depending on load - so both readings may be accurate if not taken at the exact same instance.
For the Epyc 9654, 2.4 GHz is the nominal/base clock rate, indicating light load. 3.7 GHz is the maximum boost rate, indicating full load.
Also, -f uses cpufreq as source, while -w reads "from hardware" (requiring root privileges), so the -w reading may be more recent.
